predicting safe addresses
given identical salt and other options (owner, threshold) and deploying two safes on respectively gnosis and base, i would expect the predicted safe address to be the same. But somehow they are not. I am using my own paymaster contracts and those addresses differ. The bundlers are from pimlico. The entrypoints are both v0.6 and have the same address. It cant be the nonce, as this single signer key has just been created, right? Suggestions are appreciated. I feel a bit stuck.

paymaster addresses need to be the same
